# Why would these parameters for this model be problematic?

Tags: time-series, arima

I had question related to this ARIMA result that I have screenshot of here. The question is "Comment on the fit characteristics of this model in terms of model parameters (for which model we can estimate its parameters with more precision?) and their value for out of sample prediction (which model is likely to produce better out-of-sample forecasts? Explain."

It is stated in the answer to this question that phis for this model are problematic. I don't really understand why they would be problematic. Could anyone explain this to me?

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify your question?

Comment: I tried to clarify a bit more. Thanks for the feedback.